# How to set a combobox value

Tags: c#, winforms

Yesterday i asked this question: [Get current time and set a value in a combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244470/get-current-time-and-set-a-value-in-a-combobox)

Now i´m having another issue that i have to deal with. In the question that i asked yesterday i had three times zones in my combobox:

06:00 - 14:00 the combobox will get the value **TimeZone 1**

14:01 - 22:00 the combobox will get the value **TimeZone 2**

22:01 - 05:59 the combobox will get the value **TimeZone 3**

And i also have a datTimePicker were the user can choose a date. Let´s say that the user choose: 2011-02-02 and in the timezone combobox choose TimeZone 2. If this happens i want to create a method that only search for the time. between 14:01 - 22:00 (wich are TimeZone 2). And if the user choose TimeZone 3 it will only search for the time between 22:01 - 05:59.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "search for time"?

Comment: I have a database wich contains data, and if the user chooses TimeZone 1 for example, the program will search for orders between: 06:00 - 14:00.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem with this? The database connection? Formulating the SQL query? Usage of EF, NHibernate or LINQ2SQL? Please, try to be more specific with your questions, we can't magically know, what you want to do!

Comment: i think we need to know what kind of db you use and how do you select the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Period holder class containing the Type, the from and to time. This can be inserted into a collection like a IList which can be used as datasource for your combobox. Something like this example:

```
    [Test]
    public void CompositeDictionary()
    {

        //Create a dictionary of periods
        IList<PeriodHolder> periodHolders = new List<PeriodHolder>();
        periodHolders.Add(new PeriodHolder("Type1", "06:00", "14:00"));
        periodHolders.Add(new PeriodHolder("Type2", "14:01", "22:00"));
        periodHolders.Add(new PeriodHolder("Type3", "22:01", "05:59"));

        //Create the test combobox in a test form
        Form testForm = new Form();
        ComboBox testComoBox = new ComboBox();
        testForm.Controls.Add(testComoBox);

        testComoBox.DataSource = periodHolders;
        testComoBox.ValueMember = "PeriodName"; //The name of the Name property in PeriodHolder
        testComoBox.DisplayMember = "PeriodString"; //The name of the PeriodString property in PeriodHolder
        testComoBox.SelectedIndex = 1;


        string selectedType = testComoBox.ValueMember[testComoBox.SelectedIndex].ToString(); //Get the type so you can lookup in dictionary


        foreach (PeriodHolder periodHolder in periodHolders)
        {
            if (periodHolder.PeriodName == selectedType)
            {
                //Use period holder for whatever you need

                string fromTime = periodHolder.TimeFrom; //Extract fromTime from periodholder
                string toTime = periodHolder.TimeTo;     //Extract toTime from periodholder

                Console.WriteLine(periodHolder.PeriodString);

                break; //you've found it -- Don't look anymore
            }
        }



    }

    public class PeriodHolder
    {
        public PeriodHolder(string name, string from, string to)
        {
            PeriodName= name;
            TimeFrom =from;
            TimeTo = to;
        }
        public string PeriodName { get; set; }
        public string TimeFrom { get; set; }
        public string TimeTo { get; set; }

        public string PeriodString
        {
            get
            {
                return TimeFrom + " - " + TimeFrom;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method with 3 input parameters like GetTime(DateTimePickerValue, TimeZone, SearchedTimeDate) and return value bool.

Check out method TimeSpan to calculate time and dates.