# Set combobox's value member programmatically

Tags: vb.net, combobox, visual-studio-2012, selectedvalue

I've been looking around for this answer.  Checked here: [How to set a combobox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257016/how-to-set-a-combobox-value) but I'm not sure if it applies to me (could be wrong, please correct me if I am).  I'm using VB.Net, VS2012 and I need to programmatically set the value member of a combobox that is databound.

My code now is as follows (this is from within a loop assigning a bunch of controls values):

```
    cboCountry.SelectedValue = row.Item("CCCOUNTRY").ToString
```

This does not assign any selected value.  I have also tried:

```
    cboCountry.SelectedItem = cboCountry.FindString(row.Item("CCCOUNTRY").ToString)
```

But this does not work either.  For this instance:

1. I have one combobox
2. It has two values databound in it's valuemember properties, "US", and "CA"
3. The row item that I'm assigning it is one of those values.

Again, all I need to do is set the selectedvalue programmatically.  Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're close on your second try -- replace SelectedItem with SelectedIndex:

```
cboCountry.SelectedIndex = cboCountry.FindString(row.Item("CCCOUNTRY").ToString)
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me today in vb.net vs2010

cboCountry.SelectedIndex = cboCountry.FindString("CCCOUNTRY").ToString

The names of the controls and values for me were different, but I continued the previous users posts...

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
cboCountry.Items.FindByText(row.Item("CCCOUNTRY").ToString()).Selected = True
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in a project with VB.NET VS2010

```
cboCountry.SelectedIndex = cboCountry.FindString("CCCOUNTRY").ToString
```

of course the project has different names and values

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing the same problem and have not found an answer on the 
net.  Apparently, Microsoft has not fixed this problem yet.  I am using VB for a VS2010 WinForms app (in Windows 7).  I finally decided to code a work around,  Wherever I was trying to preset the selected value of a ComboBox I made the following change:

```
' my_cbx.SelectedValue = data_row.value  ' doesn't work!
PresetSelectedValue(my_cbx, data_row.value)
```

Then, I added the following subroutine to be called by the above changes:

```
Public Sub PresetSelectedValue(ByRef ComboBox As ComboBox, ByVal value As Object)
    Dim item_ndx As Integer

    If ComboBox Is Nothing Then
        '   throw exception?
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With ComboBox
        .Tag = "PresetSelectedValue"
        For item_ndx = 0 To .Items.Count - 1
            .SelectedIndex = item_ndx
            If .SelectedValue = value Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If item_ndx >= .Items.Count Then
            .SelectedIndex = -1
        End If
        .Tag = ""
    End With
End Sub
```

Finally, I added the following code to my ComboBox.SelectedValueChanged event 
(this prevents the normal event logic  when user changes the value from being 
executed on every iteration of the For loop in my subroutine above):

```
If my_cbx.Tag = "PresetSelectedValue" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
combobox.SelectedIndex = combobox.Items.IndexOf(someString)
```

`someString` should be in the list of values of the `combobox`.